# Hive - Filter values that do not fall in multiple ranges/intervals

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have two tables, Table_A and Table_B.

**Table_A:**

```
Value       
-----
1001        
2001        
3001        
4001        
5001
```

**Table_B:**

```
Min             Max
---             ---
1000            2000
3000            4000
5000            6000
7000            8000
9000            10000
```

I need to get those records from Table_A which **do not fall between any of the intervals/ranges** in master Table_B.

Result expected:

```
Value
-----
2001
4001
```

Please let know the approach to write my Hive query to get the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do this with a `cross join` and aggregation:

```
select a.value
from table_a a cross join
     table_b b
group by a.value
having sum(case when a.value between b.min and b.max then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one using a join and a NOT IN statement:

```
SELECT value
FROM table_a
WHERE value NOT IN
(SELECT value
 FROM table_a
 INNER JOIN table_b
 ON table_a.value BETWEEN table_b.min AND table_b.max)
```

Tested here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6685c/1